# SQL UNION query with order by giving syntax error on "("

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, union

I'm trying to select 2 oldest females and 2 oldest males using 1 query. The union keeps giving me a syntax error near "(". Both queries work independantly but after union I get error.

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE students (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender TEXT NOT NULL,
  age INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- insert some values
INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'Ryan', 'M', 23);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (2, 'Joanna', 'F', 22);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (3, 'Alex', 'F', 25);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (4, 'Ted', 'M', 21);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (5, 'June', 'F', 26);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (6, 'Rose', 'F', 24);
INSERT INTO students VALUES (7, 'Jack', 'M', 25);

-- select * from students;

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT name FROM students WHERE GENDER = 'F' ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 2) 
UNION 
(SELECT name FROM students WHERE GENDER = 'M' ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 2);
```

Comment: Doesn't work :( .

Comment: check this : https://www.mycompiler.io/view/HXr76zOKaOj

Comment: So i think your solution is correct but the mycompiler website I'm using generates an error for some reason. If you can confirm your solution doesn't work there then it's probably their fault.

Comment: The DBMS tagging is wrong. Fixed. MySQL removed, SQLite added.

Answer (score 0):

Your online compliler uses not MySQL but SQLite!

Execute `select sqlite_version();` - the output is `'3.31.1'`.

---

Use this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gender ORDER BY age DESC) rn
     FROM students
     ) 
SELECT name 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= 2;
```

This code is correct for SQLite.

PS. Add `ORDER BY` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

For SQLite, both unioned queries, since they contain an `ORDER BY` clause, must be used as subqueries with an external `SELECT` clause and you can use an `ORDER BY` clause at the end which will be applied to the resultset of the union and will put all `F`s at the top because they are alphabetically less than the `M`s:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM students WHERE gender = 'F' ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 2)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM students WHERE gender = 'M' ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY gender, age;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9726f3f54af185d4e16a9e4fe5b0615e).